# Listbox Bound to a PSObject list DisplayMember not working

Tags: winforms, powershell, data-binding, listbox, psobject

I have a form with a `listbox` on it. In this `listbox` I want to put `PSObjects` that have these members: Name, Location, ID.

I have created a variable: `$list` that holds all the `PSObjects` and I want to bind `$list` to the `$listbox` so that anytime `$list` is modified the `$listbox` automatically updates.

I am able to bind `$list` to the `$listbox` but it doesn't display it properly. I would like only the name member to be visible. The problem is, regardless of if I set the `DisplayMember` property or not, the `$list` is still displayed like this:

```
_______________________________________
|@{Name=Jim; Location=Somewhere; ID=0}|
|@{Name=Sam; Location=Somewhere; ID=1}|
|_____________________________________|
```

I want it to look like this:

```
______
|Jim |
|Sam |
|____|
```

Here's the relevant code I'm working with:

```
    #####PSObject Initialization Code:##########
$obj1 = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    'Name' = 'Jim';'Location' = 'Somewhere';'ID' = 0
};$obj2 = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    'Name' = 'Sam';'Location' = 'Somewhere';'ID' = 1
};$list = $obj1,$obj2
    #####Listbox Code:##########################
$listbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listbox.Dock = 'Fill'
$listbox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'
$listbox.DisplayMember = 'Name'
$listbox.DataSource = $list
    #####Form Code##############################
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”)
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Drawing”)
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500)
$form.Controls.Add($listbox); $form.ShowDialog()
```

Does anyone have an idea about why the `DisplayMember` property is seemingly overlooked when I bind the list and how to get the display into the desired format?

**Note:** If the `PSObjects` are added from the list one at a time, then it displays properly, but this gets clunky in my application.

Comment: Try: `$listbox.DataSource = $List | Select -Expand Name`

Comment: @iRon That is not the desired effect. That won't put the whole PSObject into the listbox, only the names.

Comment: Can you post a minimum reproducible example?  I haven't exactly got code sitting around that creates a Form and puts a ListBox on it.

Comment: Bacon Bits I have added form initialization code as you requested as well as how to initialize the PSObjects and list.

Comment: This question is old but man I'm, having the exact same issue and it's driving me nutso.
The array I'm building the listbox from was generated from importing json files (ConvertFrom-Json) and the listbox is just displaying the raw object data.  But if I grab any item from the array and call.name -works lie a charm.  I wonder if you ever figured this out
Oh and I gotta say.. this question is well done.  The dialog drawings, etc. amazing

Answer (score 0):

Figured I would post this even if it's old, a bunch of folk have looked

The trick was to cast the array as an arraylist:

```
$listbox.DataSource = [system.collections.arraylist]$itemList
```